# Precision current source 1 nA circuit analysis

Tags: current, current-source, precision

[image: 3-OPAMP precision current source]

I couldn't find any detail explaining this circuit. How would I change it to make it operate between 1 uA to few microamps? Would change 10 Mohm to 10 kohm would greatly degrade the performance? I can see the bottom two OPs are part of an improved Howland current pump that is part of a the negative feedback loop.

https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/a-large-current-source-with-high-accuracy-and-fast-settling.html

What does the top opamp do with the feedback? It'd be awesome if someone could write a follow-up article on this 3-opamp like Nick's article.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that the top op amp subtracts 0.1% of the input voltage from the voltage across the 10M\$\Omega\$ sense resistor with a large DC gain.

The bottom left op-amp is a trimmed differential amplifier (trimmed to maximize common-mode rejection) that subtracts the buffered voltage across the load from the voltage at the top of the 10M\$\Omega\$ resistor.

The remaining op-amp is a unity-gain amplifier that buffers the high-impedance node where the 10M\$\Omega\$ resistor connects to the load.

The 3.9pF capacitor and 10nF capacitor/series 100\$\Omega\$ resistor are intended to stabilize the closed-loop circuit.

So the net result is that 0.1% of the input voltage appears across the 10M\$\Omega\$ resistor connected to the load, so the load current is Vin/K where K = 10G\$\Omega\$.

---

The circuit shows off the capabilities of the manufacturer's product, which combines a relatively low (70uV) input offset voltage and drift, plus a relatively low input bias current (1pA at 25°C and 40pA at up to 85°C), plus rail-to-rail inputs and outputs. You can also detect an issue- the maximum supply voltage of this part is only a few volts, so the compliance of the output is limited to less than 2.5V.

---

Why would you use such a circuit? You probably wouldn't (and shouldn't) use a Howland-style source at all unless you wanted a **bipolar** voltage-controlled current source. The output impedance (ideally infinite) is very sensitive to the CMRR of the differential amplifier, so we end up with a circuit that will degrade as resistors drift and that requires a multi-turn trimpot and adjustment during manufacture.

There are much simpler and more robust unipolar sources and sinks that do not require as much effort to compensate and do not depend on precise matching of parts to have a very high output impedance.

If you are not working with a circuit where pA matter you could use a much less expensive non-boutique op-amp that is capable of dealing with  higher voltage supplies. You might be able to use a few-penny LM324 that has been around for decades and will be around for decades longer. A pass element such as a jellybean BJT or MOSFET will suffice at more sensible currents.

You might be able to use a single supply rail, instead of the four rails that are implied with this circuit (+/-2.5 for the above circuit and probably +/-12 or +/-15V for the control voltage).

Comment: I do want to use bipolar but a single transistor can either only source or sink.  I want the range is 1uA~1 mA and compliance voltage is +/- 20V. I'm uncertain if 1uA range is considered big or small as @mmmm mentioned about different type of compensations. LM324 has Vos few mVs.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wouldn't use this schematic at all - a simpler constant current source would work. The nA range is more challenging than the uA range, as you start to have to compensate the currents flowing into the opamp inputs.

I'd honestly look for the MOSFET-based opamp precision current source circuit, and check whether the error terms I can achieve with the opamps I have are acceptably low.